# Magento 2 delete product from shopping cart page (My remove button is in default.phtml file)

Tags: magento2

Hi I moved my remove button to Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item\default.phtml now how can i delete the product?

Comment: its working like this : <a href="#"   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove item')); ?>"
   class="action action-delete" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;delete\/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;<?php echo $item_id;?>&quot;}}" >
    <span>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Remove item')?>
    </span>
</a>